# Trying to use extern int, told it's now a pointer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, extern

I've declared this little guy in the `Constants.h` file of my project:

`extern int *exitDirection;`

Then, I set him to an integer. In this case, it was 881, which is a very nice number.

Now, I want to use him in a switch statement elsewhere in the project:

```
    switch (exitDirection) {
        case kExitDirectionLeft:
            // Have him spawn on the right of the next level.
            break;
        case kExitDirectionRight:
            // Have him spawn on the left of the next level.
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm being given the lovely error message `"Statement requires expression of integer type (int * invalid)`, which I assume means that I'm giving it a pointer to an integer, as opposed to an actual integer. The kExitDirectionLeft is just `#define`'d as 881, I've tried switching it with an actual number, no joy. Also tried switching int to NSNumber or NSInteger, same error.

Why can't I use this externally defined integer in this case? How can I make it work? Any help appreciated!

Fixed it, but in doing so I'm now triggering this Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error..

```
"_exitDirection", referenced from: 
  -[GameplayLayer positionHeroMale] in GameplayLayer.o
  -[GameCharacter checkAndClampSpritePosition] in GameCharacter.o
  -[GameplayLayer positionHeroMale] in GameplayLayer.o
  -[GameCharacter checkAndClampSpritePosition] in GameCharacter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What you actually did was tell it to point to the integer at memory location 881 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extern int *exitDirection;
```

Here you actually declared pointer to the int, you probably (depending on how you create it and set value to it) need just plain int here:

```
extern int exitDirection;
```

Also with that declaration you just tell compiler that exitDirection is created somewhere outside of the current scope, the variable itself is not created. You need to actually create (and probably set some initial value to it) in some implementation file, e.g.:

```
// Constants.m
int exitDirection = 0;
```

Comment: That was correct. Seems I've now trigged an Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error though..
`  "_exitDirection", referenced from:
      -[GameplayLayer positionHeroMale] in GameplayLayer.o
      -[GameCharacter checkAndClampSpritePosition] in GameCharacter.o
      -[GameplayLayer positionHeroMale] in GameplayLayer.o
      -[GameCharacter checkAndClampSpritePosition] in GameCharacter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any ideas?

Comment: I currently don't have a constants.m file. If I try to add one, I get errors about a missing @interface to go with the implementation – any way around that?

Comment: You probably have  "@implementation Constants ..." code block created for you - you can just delete it leaving only int exitDirection = 0; in the file (and also #import "Constants.h")

Answer (score 1):

You declared `exitDirection` as an `int` pointer and you need to `switch` on an `int`. Either change `exitDirection` to an `int` or do the following

```
switch(*exitDirection)
{
     ...
}
```